# send multiple params to web service

Tags: ios, ruby, json, web-services, parameters

I have a JSON like this.

```
[
   {
      "created_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:16Z",
      "id": 80,
      "order_date": "2012-05-07 22:17:14",
      "order_done": false,
      "order_total": "14.7",
      "order_uuid": "e10655868d12d9855b83e02efb026eef056f1d92",
      "updated_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:17Z",
      "order_details": [
         {
            "created_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:17Z",
            "food_count": 2,
            "food_name": "Baileys Shaken with Ice",
            "food_place": "El Gringo Music Saloon",
            "food_price": "8.4",
            "id": 146,
            "order_id": 80,
            "updated_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:17Z"
         },
         {
            "created_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:17Z",
            "food_count": 1,
            "food_name": "Baileys Irish Martini",
            "food_place": "O'Malley's",
            "food_price": "6.3",
            "id": 147,
            "order_id": 80,
            "updated_at": "2012-05-07T19:17:17Z"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now I wanna send them to Ruby Web Service from iOS.

Is it possile using one request POST to send them to web service?

now I use 2 request POST or 1 request POST and 1 request UPDATE => ITS BAD!!!!

Answer (score 2):

i think it will be good if you get started with some tutorials about web using services and  JSON. Like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) or [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) or even [this](https://www.google.com.tr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+use+json+in+ios+app)

Comment: I dont think your idea is good. Im stuck with this JSON. not JSON basic.

Comment: if you share all your row JSON data it means you dont know a lot about web things(i do know from myself:) I hope these links help..

Answer (score 0):

Setup `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details` in your `Order` model in order to accept the array you're pushing in :)

Comment: {"order":{"order_date":"bbbbbbbb","order_done":"0","order_details_attributes":{"orderdetail":[{"food_price":"eeeeee","food_place":"fffffff","food_name":"ddddd"},{"food_price":"eeeeee","food_place":"fffffff","food_name":"ddddd"}]},"order_uuid":"6011a455de8342c42570097ca2f9e9a0c8f77a27"}}

Comment: {"order":{"order_date":"bbbbbbbb","order_done":"0","order_details_attributes":[{"orderdetail":{"food_price":"eeeeee","food_place":"fffffff","food_name":"ddddd"}},{"orderdetail":{"food_price":"eeeeee","food_place":"fffffff","food_name":"ddddd"}}],"order_uuid":"6011a455de8342c42570097ca2f9e9a0c8f77a27"}}

Comment: both JSONs is deny by Web service.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said. but its unsuccessful.